# How to change label background color dynamically in Kivy

Tags: python, canvas, label, kivy

I try to make a simple ToDoList program.There are add, remove and do it buttons. But I have some bugs about labels color. When I click "DO IT" button label color change in scrollview but when I click remove button when some of them done, colored labels change. I did using canvas. How can I fix this problem?

```py
class Home(Screen):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Home,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def addWidget(self):
        task_input = self.ids.task_input.text
        newListItem = EachTask(text=task_input , 
        id=str((len(self.ids.add_field.children))) )
        print(newListItem.id)
        self.ids.add_field.add_widget(newListItem)
class EachTask(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, text= "", **kwargs):
        super(EachTask,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.label.text = text

    def Do_Task(self,instance):
        child = instance.parent.parent
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(.5,1,.2,1, mode='rgba')
            Rectangle(pos=child.ids.label.pos, size=child.ids.label.size)
```

### kv_file

```kv
<FlatButton@ButtonBehavior+Label>:
    font_size: 15


<Home>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: home
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: 5
        #space_x: self.size[0]/2
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (1,1,1,1)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

    ##########HEADER#######
        BoxLayout:
            id: header
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (.85,.7,.2,1)
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            Label:
                text: "TO DO LIST"
                font_size: "20sp"
                bold: True
                size_hint_x: .9
            FlatButton:
                text: "Back"
                size_hint_x: .1
    ####################################
        ScrollView:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (1,1,.2,.2)
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            BoxLayout:
                id: add_field
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
                spacing: 2   #Spaces between childs
    #####################################################
        BoxLayout:
            id: input_field
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 80
            TextInput:
                id: task_input
                focus: True
                size_hint_x: .9
                multiline: False
            Button:
                font_size: "40sp"
                size_hint_x: .1
                text: "+"
                on_release: root.addWidget()
                id: button1
                color: 1,0.5,0.5,1
#######################################################
<EachTask>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 50
    id: each_task
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            size_hint_x: .8
            id: label
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (1,.2,.2,.2)
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
        Button:
            size_hint_x: .1
            text: "X"
            on_release: app.root.ids.add_field.remove_widget(root)
        Button:
            size_hint_x: .1
            text: "DO IT"
            on_release: root.Do_Task(self)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following enhancements are required to the kv and py files to solve the problem.

## Method 1 - Kivy automatically created & added an ObjectProperty, `rgba`

[Kivy automatically created & added an ObjectProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#syntax-of-a-kv-file)

> If the widget doesn’t have a property with the given name, an
>   [ObjectProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ObjectProperty) will be automatically created and added to the widget.

### kv file

1. Add a class attribute, `rgba` and initialize it to default colour, `(1, .2, .2, .2)` to class rule, `<EachTask>:`
2. Replace label's colour to `root.rgba`

#### Snippets - kv file

```
<EachTask>:
    rgba: (1,.2,.2,.2)    # Kivy auto created & added ObjectProperty, "rgba"
    ...
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            size_hint_x: .8
            id: label
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: root.rgba
                ...
```

### py file

1. Remove all the codes in method `Do_Task()`
2. Add `self.rgba = [.5, 1, .2, 1]` whereby `self` refers to the current widget i.e. `EachTask` object.

#### Snippets - py file

```
def Do_Task(self, instance):
    self.rgba = [.5, 1, .2, 1]
```

## Method 2 - Explicitly declaring `rgba`

### kv file

1. Replace `rgba: (1,.2,.2,.2)` with `root.rgba`

#### Snippets - kv file

```
<EachTask>:
    ...
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            size_hint_x: .8
            id: label
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: root.rgba
                ...
```

### py file

1. Add import statement, `from kivy.properties import ListProperty`
2. Declare class attribute, `rgba` of `ListProperty` type and initilaize it to default colour, `[1, .2, .2, .2]` in class `EachTask()`
3. Remove all the codes in method `Do_Task()`
4. Add `self.rgba = [.5, 1, .2, 1]` whereby `self` refers to the current widget i.e. `EachTask` object.

#### Snippets - py file

```
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
...
class EachTask(BoxLayout):
    rgba = ListProperty([1, .2, .2, .2])
    ...
    def Do_Task(self, instance):
        self.rgba = [.5, 1, .2, 1]
```